# Table @media query display issue

Tags: css, css-tables

I have created a table where I have 5 cell in 1 row I want to show all cell together in 900px width, and if the screen size comes down the table should show 4 cells in first row and 1 in second row and so on till 1 cell in each row for mobile viewing. I have posted the code here https://jsfiddle.net/e8hsmubv/

CSS Code-

```
@media all and (max-width:565px){
table{
    width:100%;
}
td{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
tr{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:00px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set this **style** first on your **table**
 **`border-collapse: separate;`** and add **`display:inline-block`** to **`td`**. Declare it before **@media** Then that would do :).

Comment: i see now, declare the **`table {border-collapse: separate;}`** before the @media like how you did to **`td {display:inline-block;}`**. also, remove **`width:100%`** on the **`td`** because it turns  a `display:inline-block` to `display:block` output.